# Function App blob triggers stopped working

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-trigger

Sorry if in wrong place - please let me know where this should go.

We're using blob triggers in a Function App to detect new files.

Function Extension Version ~4, Node.js 16 LTS.

Expected behaviour: new file added to container/path triggers the Function App.

**Problem:**
Function App + blob triggers has been working fine for around 2 months until 25/7/2022 AEST when triggers (2 blob triggers in 2 functions under the 1 app) just stopped working.

**Steps to reproduce:**
Drop a file in container and blob trigger never triggers.

Edit: Redeploy to a new Function App (different Resource Group), same codebase, different storage account as target. Working for a day, then blob triggers stopped working.

**Debug:**
Weirdly, I can run the functions from VS Code just fine.
I've checked connection strings for storage and AzureWebJobs are correct and to the right storage - they are (in any case, we've not changed them).

Checking Application Insights, I see an error: Missing workitem Storage Queues: azure-webjobs-blobtrigger-functionappname

However, the queue is definitely there.

Upon raising ticket with MSFT Unified Support, it was noted that there was a Function Cloud platform upgrade from version 4.5.1.18321 to 4.7.2.18626 at almost exactly the same time.

We were advised to update our host.json file from the below (bolding mine).

I'm going to change the extensionBundle version to "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)" - I'll be doing that tomorrow.

I've gone back to MSFT with some questions.

Weirdly, after logging in to Azure Portal tonight I can see our Function App version has changed to ~3 and Node to 12, changes which we didn't make.

Has anyone ever seen this? So far as I can tell the only  thing that's changed is the FA platform upgrade.

Comment: Offline discussion and will be updating this thread post our discussion. Similar thread : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/942597/index.html

Comment: Yep, thanks Mayank. Cross posted in case someone here had seen it and was not on MSFT site.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved or per the discussion internally.

Storage account was terminated with a private endpoint and private endpoint aliased to the storage acct URI in our private/custom DNS.

However, the queue endpoint was not terminated in a private endpoint.

The NSG rules which allowed egress to public internet was disabled, which blocked access to the queues (on a public IP).

Restoring the rule restored access.